# Generate random letter by frequency

Tags: javascript, comparative-review, random

Which method below should I use to generate a "random letter by frequency" using Javascript?

From https://gist.github.com/furf/2413792

```
var randomAtoZ = (function (lookup) {
    return function () {
        var random = Math.random() * 100000,
                letter;
        for (letter in lookup) {
            if (random < lookup[letter]) {
                return letter;
            }
        }
    }
})({
    // Ranges calculated from data found at
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency
    a: 8167,  b: 9659,  c: 12441, d: 16694,
    e: 29396, f: 31624, g: 33639, h: 39733,
    i: 46699, j: 46852, k: 47624, l: 51649,
    m: 54055, n: 60804, o: 68311, p: 70240,
    q: 70335, r: 76322, s: 82649, t: 91705,
    u: 94463, v: 95441, w: 97801, x: 97951,
    y: 99925, z: 100000
});
```

My re-write

```
function randomAtoZ() {
    // Ranges calculated from data found at
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency
    var lookup = {
        a: 8167,  b: 9659,  c: 12441, d: 16694,
        e: 29396, f: 31624, g: 33639, h: 39733,
        i: 46699, j: 46852, k: 47624, l: 51649,
        m: 54055, n: 60804, o: 68311, p: 70240,
        q: 70335, r: 76322, s: 82649, t: 91705,
        u: 94463, v: 95441, w: 97801, x: 97951,
        y: 99925, z: 100000
    };

    var random = Math.random() * 100000;

    for (letter in lookup) {
        if (lookup[letter] > random) {
            return letter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jsperf.com/codereview-162558/1 The first uses closure, hence performs better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focusing on performance, I recommend to split the lookup table into an array of letters and an array of cumulative relative frequencies.

Iterating and accessing compact array elements is much faster compared to accessing object properties.

Also, in contrast to array iteration, the `for..in` iteration order of object properties [is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) and thus less robust (as pointed out by Mike Brant in the comments).

Moving the lookup table out of the function body into either a closure or a module level constant gives you a speed advantage at least for non-optimizing JavaScript compilers.

A binary search strategy would find the letter corresponding to a random frequency value in O(log n) steps compared to O(n) steps for the current linear search. However, the constant binary search overhead is too big and the array small enough that the linear search performs better in practice.

I get the following [performance test](https://jsperf.com/random-letter-relative-frequency/1) results in Firefox 53:

```
Test:                 Ops/sec:
Original               1,787,627   94% slower
Linear array search   31,399,828   fastest
Binary array search   28,691,914   9% slower
```

See also the [performance test](https://jsperf.com/codereview-162558/1) given by @hjpotter92 in the comments.

Here is the winning linear array search module implementation:

```
/** English language alphabet. */
export const letters = [
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
    'q', 'r', 's', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
    'y', 'z'
];

/** 
 * English language cumulative letter frequencies × 100000.
 * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency
 */
export const frequencies = [
    8167,  9659,  12441, 16694,
    29396, 31624, 33639, 39733,
    46699, 46852, 47624, 51649,
    54055, 60804, 68311, 70240,
    70335, 76322, 82649, 91705,
    94463, 95441, 97801, 97951,
    99925, 100000
];

/**
 * Return a random letter from a - z according to their relative
 * frequencies in the English language.
 *
 * @return {string} random letter from a - z.
 */
export default function randomAtoZ() {
  let random = Math.random() * 100000;
  for (let i = 0, length = letters.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (random < frequencies[i]) {
      return letters[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be further improved by using `frequencies.findIndex()`

Comment: @MarcRohloff Perhaps I misunderstood, but IMHO you would need something like `frequencies.floorIndex(random)` which returns the index of the biggest cumulative frequency less than or equal to `random`. I already tried that - see the binary search case at https://jsperf.com/random-letter-relative-frequency/1 - with mediocre results.

Comment: I was thinking o replacing the `for ...` with ` .. `const i =  frequencies.findIndex(el -> random < el); return letters[i];` which might be fractionally faster since it is an internal function. I doubt a binary search would help much on such a small array

Comment: @MarcRohloff It runs suspiciously slow in FF, perhaps you have better luck in Chrome: https://jsperf.com/random-letter-relative-frequency

Comment: +1 This is not to mention that iteration order of properties of objects in javascript is technically not guaranteed to be ordered (though the original solutions would work with de facto browser implementations). So if you want the the algorithm to work **for sure** you need to use arrays or a Map to guarantee iteration order.

Comment: @MikeBrant Good point, I added that to the review.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the second one for simplicity. I'm pretty the first one used the closure so that the letter-frequency key-value pair is only created once and referenced by the returned function. But at this scale, the performance hit for creating the key-value pair is probably negligible.

Also, you could also use `Object.keys` together with `array.find` instead of a `for` loop and a return.

```
function randomAtoZ() {

    const lookup = {
        a: 8167,  b: 9659,  c: 12441, d: 16694,
        e: 29396, f: 31624, g: 33639, h: 39733,
        i: 46699, j: 46852, k: 47624, l: 51649,
        m: 54055, n: 60804, o: 68311, p: 70240,
        q: 70335, r: 76322, s: 82649, t: 91705,
        u: 94463, v: 95441, w: 97801, x: 97951,
        y: 99925, z: 100000
    };

    const random = Math.random() * 100000;

    return Object.keys(lookup).find(k => lookup[k] > random);
}
```

Comment: PS: I tried the binary search you previously suggested and found that it runs slower than a linear search on arrays. Might be a little bit faster on objects / maps due to higher property lookup cost.

Comment: @le_m Exactly why it's not in my answer anymore like an hour ago.